Brightcove Analytics on Sitecore 9.2 Website
We have integrated Brightcove with Sitecore, and our sites are gated. We have a requirement for videos to resume from where the user left off.
We are attempting to achieve this using the following code:
async function setContinueWatchingVideo() {
        var viewerId = '@userId', baseURL = '@xdrApiBaseUrl';
        if (viewerId != "") {
            var accountId = playerData.accountId, options = {};
            options.proxyURL = "@xdrProxyUrl";
            options.url = baseURL + accountId + '@Constants.Brightcove.PlayHeads' + viewerId;
            options.requestType = "@xdrAnalyticsRequestType";

            try {
                const positionRaw = await makeBrightCoveRequest(options);
                const userHistories = JSON.parse(positionRaw);

                if (userHistories.message == undefined) {
                    const userWatchedVideos = JSON.parse(userHistories);

                    if (userWatchedVideos.items.length > 0) {
                        const lastWatchedVideo = userWatchedVideos.items[0];
                        const videooptions = {};
                        videooptions.proxyURL = "@cmsVideoProxyUrl";
                        videooptions.url = '@cmsApiBaseUrl' + accountId + '@Constants.Brightcove.Videos' + lastWatchedVideo.video_id;
                        videooptions.requestType = "@xdrAnalyticsRequestType";

                        try {
                            const videoDetail = await makeBrightCoveRequest(videooptions);
                            const userVideoDetail = JSON.parse(videoDetail);

                            if (userVideoDetail) {
                                const videoDetails = JSON.parse(userVideoDetail);

                                if (videoDetails.duration) {
                                    const thresoldPercentage = @thresoldLimit;
                                    var styleDisplay = "";
                                    var resumeModuleClosed = localStorage.getItem('resumeModuleClosed');
                                    if (resumeModuleClosed != "" && resumeModuleClosed != null && resumeModuleClosed != undefined && resumeModuleClosed === 'Closed') {
                                        styleDisplay = "display: none";
                                    }

                                    var counter = 0;
                                    var actualCount = 0;
                                    var isFirstTimeLoad = true;
                                    var totalVideos = userWatchedVideos.items.length;
                                    var floatingPlayerHtml = "";
                                    for (const watchedVideo of userWatchedVideos.items) {
                                        try {
                                            const forOptions = {};
                                            forOptions.proxyURL = "@cmsVideoProxyUrl";
                                            forOptions.url = '@cmsApiBaseUrl' + accountId + '@Constants.Brightcove.Videos' + watchedVideo.video_id;
                                            forOptions.requestType = "@xdrAnalyticsRequestType";

                                            const forVideoDetail = await makeBrightCoveRequest(forOptions);
                                            const firstVideoDetail = JSON.parse(forVideoDetail);
                                            if (firstVideoDetail) {
                                                var storedArrayString = localStorage.getItem('notShowVideoId');
                                                var retrievedArray = JSON.parse(storedArrayString) || [];
                                                var index = retrievedArray.indexOf(watchedVideo.video_id);

                                                const secondVideoDetail = JSON.parse(firstVideoDetail);
                                                const videoDurationSeconds = secondVideoDetail.duration / 1000;
                                                const videoPercentageSeconds = (thresoldPercentage / 100) * videoDurationSeconds;
                                                const videoWatchedSeconds = watchedVideo.playhead_seconds;
                                                counter++;

                                                if (videoWatchedSeconds > videoPercentageSeconds && (videoDurationSeconds - videoWatchedSeconds) > 2 && index === -1) {
                                                    actualCount++;
                                                    let referencePageLinkEach = "#";
                                                    try {
                                                        referencePageLinkEach = await getReferencePageURL(secondVideoDetail.id);
                                                    } catch (error) {
                                                        console.error(error);
                                                    }

                                                    var videoJSIdDefault = "@("player" + videoElementId)" + 0 + "#" + videoWatchedSeconds;
                                                    var videoJSId = "@("player" + videoElementId)" + counter + "#" + videoWatchedSeconds;
                                                    if (isFirstTimeLoad) {
                                                        window.localStorage.setItem("brightcoveVideoId", watchedVideo.video_id);
                                                        window.localStorage.setItem("videoJSId", videoJSIdDefault);
                                                        floatingPlayerHtml = "<div id='playerWrapper' class='resume-watchingModule show-up-arrow' style='" + styleDisplay + "'><div class='empower-title-module'><div class='resume-watch-title-module'><p class='resume-empower-title'>@Translate.Text("Continue Watching") <span class='badge videoCount'>" + totalVideos + "</span></p><span class='downIcon'></span></div><div class='resume-empower-close-module'><span class='closeIcon'></span></div></div><div class='videoParent'><div id='defaultVideo' class='videoOverlay'><div class='videoModule'><video-js id='" + videoJSIdDefault + "' data-video-id='" + watchedVideo.video_id + "' data-account='" + playerData.accountId + "' data-player='" + playerData.playerId + "' class='video vjs-16-9 bc-video-container' data-embed='default' data-application-id='' playsinline controls></video-js><a href='" + referencePageLinkEach + "'><button class='back-to-article-btn'><span>@Translate.Text("Back to article")</span></button></a><p class='video-text'>" + secondVideoDetail.name + "</p></div></div><div id='videoPopup' class='videoOverlay'>";
                                                        floatingPlayerHtml += `<div class='videoModule'><video-js id='${videoJSId}' data-video-id='${watchedVideo.video_id}' data-account='${playerData.accountId}' data-player='${playerData.playerId}' class="video vjs-16-9 bc-video-container" data-embed="default" data-application-id="" playsinline controls></video-js><a href='${referencePageLinkEach}'><button class="back-to-article-btn"><span>@Translate.Text("Back to article")</span></button></a><p class="video-text">${secondVideoDetail.name}</p></div>`;
                                                        isFirstTimeLoad = false;
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        floatingPlayerHtml += `<div class='videoModule'><video-js id='${videoJSId}' data-video-id='${watchedVideo.video_id}' data-account='${playerData.accountId}' data-player='${playerData.playerId}' class="video vjs-16-9 bc-video-container" data-embed="default" data-application-id="" playsinline controls></video-js><a href='${referencePageLinkEach}'><button class="back-to-article-btn"><span>@Translate.Text("Back to article")</span></button></a><p class="video-text">${secondVideoDetail.name}</p></div>`;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                if (counter === totalVideos) {
                                                    floatingPlayerHtml += "</div></div></div>";
                                                    $("body").append(floatingPlayerHtml);

                                                    var scriptId = "@("script" + videoElementId)" + counter;
                                                    initializeContineWatchPlayer(scriptId);

                                                    // if (actualCount > 0) {
                                                        // // $(".resume-watchingModule").addClass("show-up-arrow");
                                                        // $(".resume-empower-title").html("@Translate.Text("Continue Watching") <span class='videosCount badge'>" + actualCount + "</span>");
                                                    // }
                                                    if (actualCount < 2 && actualCount == 1 ) {
                                                    $(".resume-watchingModule").addClass("singleVideoModule");
                                                    $(".resume-empower-title").html("Continue Watching <span class='videosCount badge'>" + actualCount + "</span>");
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                    $(".resume-empower-title").html("Continue Watching <span class='videosCount badge'>" + actualCount + "</span>");
                                                    }

                                                    $(".closeIcon").on('click', function () {
                                                        localStorage.setItem('resumeModuleClosed', 'Closed');
                                                        $(".resume-watchingModule").css("display", "none");

                                                        videojs(localStorage.getItem("videoJSId")).pause();
                                                        addValueInLocalStorage(localStorage.getItem("brightcoveVideoId"));
                                                    });

                                                    $(".videoModule").click(function () {
                                                        $(".resume-watchingModule").removeClass("show-down-arrow");
                                                        $(".resume-watchingModule").addClass("single-video");
                                                        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                                                            $(".videoModule").removeClass("active");
                                                            $(this).addClass("active");
                                                        }

                                                        var activeVideoText = $(".videoModule.active .video-text").text();
                                                        $(".resume-empower-title").html(activeVideoText);
                                                    });

                                                    $(".resume-watch-title-module").click(function () {
                                                        if ($(".resume-watchingModule").hasClass('single-video') && $("#defaultVideo").css("display") === "block") {
                                                            $('#defaultVideo').css("display", "none");
                                                            $('#videoPopup').css("display", "block");
                                                            $(".resume-watchingModule").removeClass("single-video").addClass("show-down-arrow");
                                                            $(".videoModule").removeClass("active");
                                                        }
                                                        else if ($(".resume-watchingModule").hasClass('single-video')) {
                                                            $(".resume-watchingModule").removeClass("single-video").addClass("show-down-arrow");
                                                            $(".videoModule").removeClass("active");
                                                        }
                                                        else if ($(".resume-watchingModule").hasClass('show-down-arrow') && $("#videoPopup").css("display") === "block"){
                                                            $('#defaultVideo').css("display", "block");
                                                            $('#videoPopup').css("display", "none");
                                                            $(".resume-watchingModule").removeClass("show-down-arrow");
                                                        }
                                                        else if ($(".resume-watchingModule").hasClass('show-up-arrow') && $("#videoPopup").css("display") === "none"){
                                                            $('#defaultVideo').css("display", "none");
                                                            $('#videoPopup').css("display", "block");
                                                            $(".resume-watchingModule").addClass("show-down-arrow");
                                                        }
                                                        $(".resume-empower-title").html("@Translate.Text("Continue Watching") <span class='videosCount badge'>" + actualCount + "</span>");
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } catch (error) {
                                            console.error(error);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    }

async function onContinuePlay(e) {
         var id = e.target.id;
         localStorage.setItem("videoJSId", id);
         localStorage.setItem("brightcoveVideoId", e.target.dataset.videoId);

         Object.keys(videojs.players).forEach(function (checkId) {
             if (checkId !== id) { videojs(checkId).pause(); }
         });

         var spSetPlayer = id.split("#");
         var watchTimes = spSetPlayer[1] === undefined ? 0 : Number(spSetPlayer[1]);

         var player = videojs.getPlayer(id);
         player.ready(function () {
             if (!player.seeking()) { this.currentTime(watchTimes); }
             this.play();
         });
     }

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

To enable video resume functionality based on where a user left off, you need to utilize Brightcove Analytics. You can implement this with the following code snippet:
    <script>
  videojs.getPlayer('myPlayerID').ready(function() {
    var myPlayer = this;

    // Set the viewer id for Brightcove analytics
    myPlayer.bcAnalytics.client.setUser('viewer id');
  });
</script>

For a detailed explanation, please refer to the following documentation - https://apis.support.brightcove.com/analytics/general/analytics-api-unique-users.html

Thank you, it works perfectly!

To implement video resume functionality, you'll need to track video progress, Save the progress and resume playback. Here are the steps you can follow:

You can use Brightcove's Player API to track the video's playback progress. You can listen for events such as timeupdate to get the current playback time and store it.

    var player = videojs('my-player'); 
    player.on('timeupdate', function() {
        var currentTime = player.currentTime();
        // Save the currentTime to your backend or local storage
        saveProgress(currentTime);
    });



Save the video playback progress in a way that it can be retrieved later.

    function saveProgress(currentTime) {
        var videoId = player.mediainfo.id;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/api/saveVideoProgress", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            videoId: videoId,
            currentTime: currentTime,
            userId: currentUser.id
        }));
    }


When the user returns to the site, retrieve the saved progress and set the video to start from that point

    function loadProgress() {
        var videoId = player.mediainfo.id;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "/api/getVideoProgress?videoId=" + videoId + "&userId=" + currentUser.id, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var progress = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (progress && progress.currentTime) {
                    player.currentTime(progress.currentTime);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    
    player.ready(function() {
        loadProgress();
    });


Create backend endpoints to handle saving and retrieving the video progress.

    [Route("api/saveVideoProgress")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveVideoProgress( VideoModel model) {
        // Save the model to your database
        return Ok();
    }
    
    [Route("api/getVideoProgress")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetVideoProgress(string videoId, string userId) {
        // Retrieve the progress from your database
        return Ok();
    }

